# jQuery Error using WP Pro Quiz

Tags: jquery, wordpress

Just added the [WP Pro Quiz](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pro-quiz/) and added a quiz locally to test it. When I clicked the button to load the Quiz it is not loaded at all and I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wpProQuizFront'
```

The script that is loaded after jQuery where the error is located in is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#wpProQuiz_1').wpProQuizFront({
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'wpProQuizFront'
        quizId: 1,
        mode: 0,
        globalPoints: 1,
        timelimit: 0,
        resultsGrade: [0],
        bo: 0,
        json: {"1":{"type":"cloze_answer","id":1,"points":1,"correct":[]}}  });
});
</script>
```

It is loaded from the file WpProQuiz_View_FrontQuiz.php on line 371:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#wpProQuiz_<?php echo $this->quiz->getId(); ?>').wpProQuizFront({
        quizId: <?php echo (int)$this->quiz->getId(); ?>,
        mode: <?php echo (int)$mode; ?>,
        globalPoints: <?php echo (int)$globalPoints; ?>,
        timelimit: <?php echo (int)$this->quiz->getTimeLimit(); ?>,
        resultsGrade: <?php echo $resultsProzent; ?>,
        bo: <?php echo $bo ?>,
        json: <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>
    });
});
</script>
```

. Source HTML of Page where quiz is loaded can be seen here: http://pastebin.com/xZVCTxyE To me it seems the code is OK and that $ is coded properly to run, but clearly something is off.

I opened a question at [WordPress' Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/jquery-typeerror?replies=1), but no answer yet and as this seems to be a script bug not a specific WP issue I decided to ask for help here. Any idea how I can fix this?

**Update**

Tried a few jQuery no-conflict options like [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), but no luck yet still. Even with no.Conflict and or using another variable the error does not go away.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was that I did not have the [footer call](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer) in my footer.php which is being used by the plugin to load the JavaScript in the footer. I added this snippet for now:

```
    <?php
   /* Always have wp_footer() just before the closing </body>
    * tag of your theme, or you will break many plugins, which
    * generally use this hook to reference JavaScript files.
    */
    wp_footer();
?>
```

Thought the base theme I worked with was complete, but I was mistaken. Silly me. Al good now!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. Change the $ to jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery('#wpProQuiz_<?php echo $this->quiz->getId(); ?>').wpProQuizFront({
            quizId: <?php echo (int)$this->quiz->getId(); ?>,
            mode: <?php echo (int)$mode; ?>,
            globalPoints: <?php echo (int)$globalPoints; ?>,
            timelimit: <?php echo (int)$this->quiz->getTimeLimit(); ?>,
            resultsGrade: <?php echo $resultsProzent; ?>,
            bo: <?php echo $bo ?>,
            json: <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Then I get a similar error:
`TypeError: jQuery(...).wpProQuizFront is not a function
http://wordpress.local/quiz-test/
Line 220`

Comment: Worked for me, even though i already had the wp_footer() included.

Comment: the file path is : "/wp-content/plugins/wp-pro-quiz/lib/view/WpProQuiz_View_FrontQuiz.php" , and it has to be changed in 2 sections not only one

Comment: @rhand i am getting this error  jQuery(...).wpProQuizFront is not a function  from many days i did call footer also but actually this script in footer i dont know what i am doing wrong..can you help me ?